# How to Run a windows service as console application on client machine

Tags: c#, windows, console

I have a **self hosted windows service application** with output type as **Console application**. I have added some console logs in that service. I need to **view those logs in console window**, without writing log file in local.

Comment: What logger are you using?
I have same case in my WS, when I run it localy I configure Serilog to use Console sink otherwise I use File sink

Comment: i'm using log4net for log file creation. In that application i'm using console.writeline for console log. i need to view those console logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Debug.WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netframework-4.8) in your code and view all these Strings using the [DbgView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) and this will not need the Console to be open.

Simple as

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Your Debug String Here");
```

Answer (score 0):

this i how I do it

```
#if DEBUG
            var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                                .WriteTo.Console()
                                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                                .CreateLogger();
#else
            var log = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config).CreateLogger();
#endif
```

Comment: I'm trying to view logs in client machine. so there is no VS or IDE for adding new piece of code.

Comment: How do you log these events now? because you said that you have added logs

Comment: I got a solution. Stop service and open cmd as administrator. In cmd enter application name with extension with full path. then add -debug and press enter.
For eg: \C:windows\sample.exe -debug.
Thank you

Comment: @SanjithM do you think this would help if you run it in your main method(Entry point for Console Application)? 
if (args.Any(x => x == "-debug"))
            {
             //Console logger
            }
            else
            {
                // other loggers
            }